# Wrong log reasoning?

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2827632/), we are given a system of equations and a restriction:

> Let $a,b,c > 0$ for
>
> $$\begin{cases}
>     \log_a(b^x) & = & 2 \\
>     \log_b(c^x) & = & 2 \\
>     \log_c(a^x) & = & 5
> \end{cases}$$
>
> $x =\,\,?$
>
> $$\log_a(b^x) = 2 \iff b^x=a^2$$

We now have
$$
    b^x = a^2 \\
    c^x = b^2 \\
    a^x = c^5
$$

Adding these up and rearranging, we have

$$a^x + b^x + c^x = a^2 + b^2 + c^5$$

Now $x$ does not seem to have a consistent solution. How is this possible?

A comment suggested this might be due to 
an over-determined system, but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2827650) shows that it has the unique solution $x^3 = 20$.

From the original post, we have the following question (which was not answered)

> Looks to me like x is equal 2 different numbers at the same time which is strange, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If x could be 2 in one place and 5 in another then that would be a solution but it cannot. Instead, some terms on the left will be bigger or smaller than their counterpart on the left but these errors will cancel out when you add them up.

Comment: `Now x=2 and x=5` This does not follow. Why do you think it would?

Comment: Does the fact that $2^2+4^2=2^4+4^1$ imply that $2=4$ and $2=1$?

Comment: Updated the statement

Comment: "Looks to me like x is equal 2 different numbers at the same time."  Why do you say this?

Comment: @saulspatz That was a quote from the original post. I am asking there seems to be an inconsistent solution (as shown by OP's post) yet a consistent solution as shown by linked answer

Comment: Oh, I see.  But you say, "$x$ does not seem to have a consistent solution," which means much the same thing, I would say.  What is it about the solution to the other question that's bothering you?  I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking.  Are you deducing something from $a^x + b^x + c^x = a^2 + b^2 + c^5$ that you feel contradicts the solution?

Comment: Just because $A^x+B^y=A^w+B^z $ does not mean $x=w,y=z $.  Consider A^{\log_A B}+B^{\log_B A}=A^1+B^1=A^0+B^{\log_B (B+A-1)} $.

Comment: @qsdyebbv `That was a quote from the original post` That confusion in the linked post was cleared up by the given answers there. What kind of different answer are you looking for here by reiterating the same confusion? Perhaps you need to take a closer look at [John Wayland Bales' comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835430/wrong-log-reasoning#comment5846891_2835430) above. Sorry, but voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Suppose $2<x<5$.  Then $a^x+b^x>a^2+b^2,$ but $c^x<c^5$ and the differences balance out, as Ian noted in the very first comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "balance out"? Since we have $x = 20^{1/3}$, we have $a^{20^{1/3}} + b^{20^{1/3}} + c^{20^{1/3}} = a^2 + b^2 + c^5$ which is not true (?)

Comment: The "over determined" comment was about saying "let a,b,c" as though they were variables rather than preset constants.  That wasn't the issue.

Comment: How do you know that isn't true?  You don't know what $a,b,c$ are so that could very easily be true.

Comment: Oh. So if they were variables, the system would be over-determined, but if they were preset constants, the equation $a^{20^{1/3}} + b^{20^{1/3}} + c^{20^{1/3}} = a^2 + b^2 + c^5$ would be true?

Comment: Forget that stupid "overdetermined"  comment.  If it actually had any meaning, it is totally irrelevant.  Bottom line: You and the op of the other question made an assumption that $A^x+B^y=A^w+B^z\implies x=w;y=z $.  That simply is not true as a little thought will show you. $x $ could by a little bigger than $w $ and $y $ a little smaller than $z $.

Comment: $A^{x+e}+B^{\log_B (B^x-A^{x+e}+A^x)} = A^x+B^x $.  But $x<x+e $ and $x> \log_B (B^x-A^{x+e}+A^x)$.  $a^x+b^x+c^x=a^2+b^2+c^5$ just is not enough information to solve.

Comment: Editorial comment:  As you are asking for clarification of an existing problem, you should have asked as a comment on that question page, and not open a question on your own.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're hitting is, as someone in a comment pointed out, you're assuming that: 
$a^x + b^y + c^z = a^m + b^n + c^o \implies x=m, y=n, z=o$, but this is not true. here's a concrete counterexample:

$$ 1^4 + 2^4 + 4^4 = 1^4 + 2^8 + 4^2$$

Both sides clearly evaluate to 273, use the same constants for $a,b,c$, yet the exponents of each constant are different.

Going back to the original equation in question, it is true that there is some $x$ - specifically $20^{1/3}$ - such that $a^x + b^x + c^x = a^2 + b^2 + c^5$. The error in your logic is that you're trying to partition the sum into 3 parts and say: "$a^x = a^2$, $b^x=b^2$, $c^x = c^5$" when it is not possible to claim that these partitions of the sums are equivalent.

In actuality, *there really are three equal partitions in this equation already!* They are in fact the first three equations you provided:
$$b^x = a^2$$
$$c^x = b^2$$
$$a^x = c^5$$

Answer (score 0):

You also need $a,b,c\ne1$ or the logarithms wouldn't make sense. Rather than summing up the equations after converting to exponentials, use
$$
\log_pq=\frac{\log q}{\log p}
$$
where the unadorned $\log$ means any base you prefer. Thus you have
$$
\begin{cases}
x\log b=2\log a \\[4px]
x\log c=2\log b \\[4px]
x\log a=5\log c
\end{cases}
$$
If you multiply the three equations, you get
$$
x^3\log b\log c\log a=20\log a\log b\log c
$$
and, since none of $a$, $b$ or $c$ is $1$, you can simplify.

The system is indeed underdetermined, because you can't solve it for $a$, $b$ and $c$. Namely, using $A=\log a$, $B=\log c$ and $C=\log c$, you have
\begin{cases}
2A-xB=0 \\[4px]
2B-xC=0 \\[4px]
xA-5C=0
\end{cases}
which easily solves to
$$
A=-\frac{x^2}{4}C,\qquad B=\frac{x}{2}{C}
$$
and $C$ is a free variable (here $x=\sqrt[3]{20}$ as shown before).